# QLabel being cutoff if windows magnification is changed

Tags: qt

I've designed an app with a display screen size of `100%` (In Windows 7 OS). But now I realize when magnifying the screen to `125%,` all the labels in my app are also scaled and clipped/cut off from the screen. I don't want the app (and its widgets like Qlabel) to change its size if Windows magnification is increased.

I tried the following:

1. I tried running the app with
    `-platform windows: dpiawareness = 0`
2. Tried setting the follwoing in the `main.cpp`
   `QApplication :: setAttribute ( Qt::AA_DisableHighDpiScaling);`

However, none of them seems to work.

Why this is happening? Is there any other easy workaround to this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you do to obtain clipped labels? Did you use pixel coordinates instead of Layouts?

Comment: you should Enable it , not disable .`QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` although Windows 7 sometimes doesn't understand well , check it in windows 10